# Stage light flare effect

Tags: node-editor

I have a node composition that works for one color only. However, I want to have multiple colors have a star flare like the following picture:

[image]

I have the studio lights all set and in each hanging light, there is a circle mesh that is an emission of red or blue. How does one get the flare to get like this in cycles? Specifically, how do I make it so I can have multiple colors flare like this? This is my node:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your best render result so far?

Comment: It renders, but only one color. Either the blue or red. I can't figure out how to make both flare.

Comment: Looks like you are using a single ID mask. Why don't you try to use two? one for each colour?

Comment: I can help if you can upload the blender file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and post it here.

Comment: Here is the link. [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2586" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2586/)

Comment: I know I might seem like a mess in that file lol.

Answer (score 1):

All right, I have been working all day figuring this thing out with over-complicated shenanigans, but the answer was quite simple:
[image: Solved Problem]

As you can see first I had to separate the globe from the actual stage light cause then the whole gray part started to shine as well.

Next I tried to fix up the original nodes, but it got real messy real fast so I decided to make two frames:

1. Original
2. Edited

The Edited one is shown on top. Also you used ID Masks without defining which object you gave the ID to in the "Object" menu.

This produced the final result below. If you want you can modify the streaks to your wish.

NOTE: I know it isn't exactly realistic, but that is the closest I can get.

BTW the rendered result is 50% of the actual resolution cause it would take me hours to render the whole image. Also great work on detail.